# R - DiD (Difference in DIfference) Model

Tags: r, statistics, dummy-variable

I'm trying to set up a DiD model with R. I have a baseline phase and a treatment group. I'm trying to consider baseline and age fluence in the model. So I created two dummy variables.

```
young <- Shower_data$Age %in% c("20-29", "30-39")
old <- Shower_data$Age %in% c("40-49", "50-64", "65+")

Shower_data$young_pos <- ifelse(Shower_data$young>0, 1, 0)
Shower_data$young_neg <- ifelse(Shower_data$young<=0, 1, 0)

Shower_data$young_pos <- 1
Shower_data$young_pos [ old ] <- 0
Shower_data$young_neg <- 0
Shower_data$young_neg [ old ] <- 1

#Create a model that considers the baseline and age
model4 <- lm(Volume ~ (Shower + dummy_phase * dummy_exp_group) * (young_pos + young_neg), data = Shower_data)
summary(model4)
```

Without the age everything went as expected, but when I add the age I only get results for `young_pos` variable but not for the `young_neg`. As you can see here:

```
#Coefficients: (5 not defined because of singularities)
#                                               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)                                    45.07006    1.65499  27.233  < 2e-16 ***
#Shower                                         -0.04725    0.00819  -5.769 8.09e-09 ***
#dummy_phase                                    -5.35647    1.72401  -3.107  0.00189 ** 
#dummy_exp_grouptreatment                       -9.33660    1.95433  -4.777 1.79e-06 ***
#young_pos                                       8.11264    2.78459   2.913  0.00358 ** 
#young_neg                                            NA         NA      NA       NA    
#dummy_phase:dummy_exp_grouptreatment            6.23700    2.06968   3.014  0.00259 ** 
#Shower:young_pos                                0.07690    0.01361   5.652 1.61e-08 ***
#Shower:young_neg                                     NA         NA      NA       NA    
#dummy_phase:young_pos                          -1.38223    2.87629  -0.481  0.63084    
#dummy_phase:young_neg                                NA         NA      NA       NA    
#dummy_exp_grouptreatment:young_pos              1.94658    3.19773   0.609  0.54271    
#dummy_exp_grouptreatment:young_neg                   NA         NA      NA       NA    
#dummy_phase:dummy_exp_grouptreatment:young_pos  2.56634    3.39298   0.756  0.44944    
#dummy_phase:dummy_exp_grouptreatment:young_neg       NA         NA      NA       NA
```

As you can see only `NA` within this variable. Thanks

Comment: My guess would be you don't have a lot of data (`# ... (5 not defined because of singularities)`)...

Comment: Its hard to tell without seeing your data, but it looks like you are making your young_neg and young_pos variables mirror images of each other, so whenever one is equal to one the other is zero and vice-versa. This would be consistent with the fact that you can never estimate a parameter including the young_neg variable.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this part of you code:

```
Shower_data$young_pos <- 1
Shower_data$young_pos [ old ] <- 0
Shower_data$young_neg <- 0
Shower_data$young_neg [ old ] <- 1
```

The vector `young_pos` includes `0`s and `1`s. The vector `young_neg` includes `0`s and `1`s too. However, one vector is the exact opposite of the other. Hence, both vectors code the *same* information and the model can only estimate an effect for one of them.